# Vim Macro recording stops when in search?

Tags: vim

I have a collection of files, and I want to use vim macro to make some changes on them. In first file, I used "qa" to initiate the macro recording, and it showed "recording" in command line. Then I continued my sequence "gg" (go to beginning of the file) -->"/class" (search and jump to first class) --> do something. However, the "recording" disappeared when I started search and "reg a" only gave "a gg, nothing else...

Could anyone please tell me why macro stopped when I did a search? Is there a way search can be part of macro?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Problem solved! I just found for some reason, there are such lines in my _vimrc file...:

nnoremap : q:i
nnoremap / q/i
nnoremap ? q?i

commenting them out solved the issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32) and it's working fine